# Select items in row on a created list

Tags: c#

I am currently creating a list in the class **ExpandWindow** using a method in the class **JobComponent**. How would I access the **JobDateTime** in **JobList** from **jobDetail** and assign the value to **DateTimeTextBlock**?

Code below:

**ExpandWindow.cs**

```
    public ExpandWindow(int jobId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<JobComponent.JobList> jobDetail = JobComponent.SelectJobBooking(jobId);
    }
```

**JobComponent.cs**

```
    public static List<JobList> SelectJobBooking(int jobId)
    {
        const string query = "SELECT t1.datetime FROM booking t1 " +
                             "WHERE t1.id=@id";
        var jobList = new List<JobList>();
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DbObject.Connection))
        {
            if (DbObject.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                DbObject.OpenConnection();
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@id"), jobId);
            try
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        var item = new JobList
                        {
                            JobDateTime = dataReader["datetime"] + ""
                        };
                        jobList.Add(item);
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                    DbObject.CloseConnection();
                    return jobList;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandlingComponent.LogError(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain little further about the issue you having? Not quite clear whats the problem here is!! And also seem this will not compile as your method will not return a result always

Comment: I've rephrased the question. Hopefully it is clearer now. I have an SQL statement hat returns a list with a single row and column, and I am trying to access the item in that single row. How would I go about doing it?

Comment: Will the method always return one item?

Comment: So why the return type is `List` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you trying here, but think you will get idea how to get the JobDateTime.

```
 public ExpandWindow(int jobId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<JobComponent.JobList> jobDetail = JobComponent.SelectJobBooking(jobId);

        if(jobDetail == null) return;

        var item = jobDetail.FirstOrDefault();
        if(item == null) return;

        yourDatetimeControl.Value = item.JobDateTime;
    }
```